# How can I dynamically populate column name using Json in JQuery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json--------------------------

```
{ "data": [
  {
  "name": "Garrett Winters",
  "designation": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      },
    {
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "designation": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      }
]
}
```

HTML -----------------

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#empTable').dataTable({
            "ajax": "empdata.json",
            "async": false,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "designation"},
                {"data": "salary"},

            ]
        });   
    });
    </script>
```

Instead of hard coding the columns as name, designation, and salary, I want to read the JSON and populate the columns name.Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If every object in the response has the same shape,  you create a columns array using the keys of the first response.

```
var columnNames = Object.keys(response.data[0]) 
// Or whatever variable the data is in.  You call Object.keys() 
// with an object and it will return an array of the keys.  
//eg.  Object.keys({ 'one': 1, 'ball': 2}) will return ['one', 'ball']

var columns = columnNames.map(name => {
    return {"data": name}
});

The columns variable would be a dynamic version of your hard coded columns.
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what changes do I need to make in my code? @gvfordo